# How to execute jar file from pentaho / ETL

Tags: pentaho, etl, jobs, kettle

I need to run a jar file from pentaho ETL . I have placed my Testvmarguments.jar file in

> server/data-integration-server/tomcat/lib

. Created job,with shell script step to execute the jar file

Below is my log:-

```
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,002 - ImageImporter - Start of job execution
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,007 - ImageImporter - Starting entry [Shell] 
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,008 - Shell - Running on platform : Linux
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,008 - Shell - Executing command :    /home/Myname/MyFolder/dummy.txt 
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,014 - Shell -    (stderr) Unable to access jarfile Testvmarguments.jar INFO 02-01    17:05:59,015 - ImageImporter - Finished job entry [Shell]    (result=[false]) 
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,015 - ImageImporter - Job    execution finished 
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,017 - Kitchen - Finished!    ERROR 02-01 17:05:59,017 - Kitchen - Finished with errors 
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,017 - Kitchen - Start=2014/01/02 17:05:56.504,    Stop=2014/01/02 17:05:59.017 
INFO 02-01 17:05:59,017 - Kitchen -    Processing ended after 2 seconds.
```

Can some one help to overcome above error .

> jar file in DI environment..!!!

Please find the attachment at [link](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?155536-How-to-execute-jar-file-from-pentaho-ETL)

I reason for using shell script is to execute a jar with runtime parameters .

> java  -Dfilepath=/home/Myfolder/Myname/Test -Dname=Myname -jar
>   Testvmarguments.jar

Here is my piece of code

```
 package com.alliance.test;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class TestCommandLine
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
  {
    String filename = null;
    String employeeName = null;
    if (System.getProperty("filepath") != null) {
      filename = System.getProperty("filepath");
    }
    if (System.getProperty("name") != null) {
      employeeName = System.getProperty("name");
    }
    File file = new File(filename + "Test.txt");
    if (!file.exists())
      file.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    out.write(filename + "\n");
    out.write(employeeName);
    out.close();
    fw.close();
  }
}
```

Thanks,
Surya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied jar to libext folder.
used following statement in JS step

> var testval2 = org.wtc.pentaho.PentahoSample.testSample("surya");

Answer (score 2):

Don't call it as an external process as then your starting a new vm unnecessary.  Instead just add jar to lib folder and call it from javascript step or udjc whichever

Comment: Calling from JS , from example **"var md5_hash = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(test_value);"** . this is to call method in a class . how can i execute a jar using JS ... **thanks in advance**@Codek

Comment: I have added a piece of code and needed parameters to execute the jar file , can you please have a look @ Codek

Comment: can you please advise , what would be wrong here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568843/etl-jar-execution-from-bi-server[/link]

Answer (score 0):

Try after putting jar inside the directory folder of data-integration(server/data-integration-server/tomcat)

Comment: I copied to libext directory , still **INFO  02-01 17:52:36,800 - Shell - Executing command : /home/Myname/MyFolder/dummy.txt**
**INFO  02-01 17:52:36,809 - Shell - (stderr) Unable to access jarfile Testvmarguments.jar** @ Rahul