# ETL JAR execution from BI server

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I am trying to Execute a jar file from ETL - This works fine .
When i am trying to call same ETL from xaction - This is showing errors as ,

```
     ERROR 05-02 09:58:28,491 - Call Data Importer - org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleValueException:

 Javascript error:TypeError: Cannot call property runImageImpoter in object [JavaPackage com.MyTest.Data.Importer]. It is not a function, it is "object".
```

> (script#5)
>
> at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.addValues(ScriptValuesMod.java:458)
>   at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.processRow(ScriptValuesMod.java:689)
>   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50) at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call property
>   runImageImpoter in object [JavaPackage com.MyTest.Data.Importer]. It
>   is not a function, it is "object". (script#5) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3557)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3535)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3563)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError3(ScriptRuntime.java:3589)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3649)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2186)
>   at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c21._c0(script:5) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c21.call(script) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:401)
>   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3003)
>   at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c21.call(script) at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c21.exec(script) at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.scriptvalues_mod.ScriptValuesMod.addValues(ScriptValuesMod.java:377)
>   ... 3 more

Comment: MD5 Sample is working, here by we can call a jar file from BI server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to include respective jar files , in tomcat lib folder of both BI and DI servers

BI server

```
/home/alliance/surya/pentaho4.5/server/data-integration-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho-di/WEB-INF/lib
```

`

DI server

```
/home/alliance/surya/pentaho4.5/server/biserver-ee/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib
```